# Sharing with generated tokens and magic url in Django with DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a file sharing application similar to dropbox with django and vuejs. It was easy to implement the sharing between users for folders but I am struggling to implement it by generating a unique link and access only to that folder. I have tried using django sesame package and it allows for creation of a tokenized url to access a user permitted page but still the folder permissions are managed by owner of them. I am planning to add a list field to a folder model and store generated tokens in that list so only the ones with a matching token in that list will be able to access to that folder. But I am not sure how to apply it. Any help would be appreciated.